# Problems getting iptables-persistent to, well, persist - Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: server, iptables, firewall

I've installed iptables-persistent on Ubuntu 17.04, in order to preserve the new rule that I've added. I've committed the change to /etc/iptables/rules.v4 - the rule was added with `sudo iptables -I INPUT 7  -s 192.168.1.0/24 -i enp37s0 -j ACCEPT`.

When I reboot, though, the rule is cleared from iptables. The `netfilter-persistent.service` service appears to be running. Restarting it resolves the problem. Any ideas?

```
adam@numbersix:~$ sudo iptables -L INPUT
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
INPUT_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
INPUT_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
adam@numbersix:~$ sudo systemctl |grep netfilter
  netfilter-persistent.service        loaded active exited    netfilter persistent configuration
adam@numbersix:~$ sudo systemctl restart netfilter-persistent.service
adam@numbersix:~$ sudo systemctl |grep netfilter
  netfilter-persistent.service        loaded active exited    netfilter persistent configuration
adam@numbersix:~$ sudo iptables -L INPUT
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.1.0/24       anywhere
INPUT_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
INPUT_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited**
```

Answer (score 0):

Save current rules by using:

`sudo iptables-save > /etc/iptables.conf`

and then load them by:
 `iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.conf`

You can put `iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.conf` in your `/etc/rc.local` to auto load them on boot.

Comment: Thanks AsenM - I've already performed the 'iptables-save'.Isn't the point of the iptables-persistent package that it automates this? The question isn't "How can restore my saved iptables from file?" it is "Why does iptables-persistent not work at boot time, when it does work if I restart the service?"...

Comment: There is iptables-persistent reconfigure option you should try this one. Honestly I have no idea how to fix this i need some more information just wild guess here.